# Why the program show that the string is out of range?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm doing homework about removing some words from the string. It always shows that the string is out of range and I do not know what's wrong with my code.

There are the strings that I use to test my function:

- "The house whirled around two or three times and rose slowly"
- "through the air. Dorothy felt as if she were going up in a balloon."
- "The north and south winds met where the house stood, and made it the"
- "exact center of the cyclone."

and the following is the words that I have to remove from the above strings:

- a
- an
- A
- and
- The
- the
- in
- or
- of

The program works well for the first two lines, but it shows that it is out of range for the third line, I think that is because I have to remove the last word from the third line (i.e. "the").

```
int RemoveWordFromLine(string &line, string word)
{
  int no_of_occurence=0;
  int const length_of_stopword=word.length();
 int  const length_of_line=line.length();

 for(int j=0 ;j<=length_of_line-length_of_stopword;j++){

   if (j==0){
   if(line.substr(j,length_of_stopword)==word){

       line.replace(j,length_of_stopword," ");
       no_of_occurence++;
  }
}
if ((j-1>=0) && (j+length_of_stopword<length_of_line)){
  if ((line.substr(j-1,1)==" ") && (line.substr(j+length_of_stopword,1)==" ")){//I have to check this to ensure 'a' in "air" is not removed by the function.
    if(line.substr(j,length_of_stopword)==word){

      line.replace(j,length_of_stopword," ");
      no_of_occurence++;
 }

  }
}
```

Comment: Have you worked through the problem with a pencil and some paper to check your maths? Have you stepped through the program with your debugger? What did you find out?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Advice -- `line.substr(j-1,1)==" "` -- This is one of the worst ways to check if a single character is a space.  This could simply be `line[j-1] == ' '`

Comment: I have worked through the problem with a pencil and I cannot find out why the string is out of range.

Comment: The string *isn't* out of range. It's meaningless. The string *index* is out of range. Be precise.

Answer (score 2):

When you remove a word, the length of the string decreases. But you are still looping up to the original length of the string. A simple fix is to get rid of `length_of_line` and just call `line.length()` everywhere you need the length.

Answer (score 0):

As the [answer from David explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55437137/3723423),  you need to dynamically check for `line.length()` to take into account the transformation of your line string. This explains the out of range.

Nevertheless, there are two others problems here.

The first is when a stop-word is at the end of a line **without any whitespace following**.  This occurence would currently missed.

The second is when a line starts with the character sequence of a stop-word but continues with something else than a space (e.g. "Then" instead of "The").  In such case the replacement currently takes place whereas it should not.

You could solve the two problems as follows:

```
for(int j=0 ;j<=line.length()-length_of_stopword;j++){
    if ( j+length_of_stopword<=line.length()){
        if ((j==0 || line[j-1]==' ') && (j+length_of_stopword==line.length() 
           || line[j+length_of_stopword]==' ' ) ) {
            if(line.substr(j,length_of_stopword)==word){
                line.replace(j,length_of_stopword,"*");
                no_of_occurence++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/2rs03U)